# How to save and retrieve buttons from DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, image, datagridview

I want to use DataGridView to store images and buttons (with links in them) in MySQL; and also to retrieve them later so that when someone presses the button, he will redirect to (the link related to) the stored image:

```
____|_x__|_y__|_z__|[new column ]
____|_11_|_12_|_13_|[text/button] <==\
____|_20_|_30_|_40_|[text/button] <== } Add text if something or button if something else.
____|_50_|_60_|_70_|[text/button] <==/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to apply names and put hyperlinks in button in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899589/how-to-apply-names-and-put-hyperlinks-in-button-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **event bubbling** for a data control.

Could you please explain it in more detail so that I can help you?

Do you want to fire button_click() event or you want to do something else?

Comment: hii bro   im working on a windows phone app which i want to connect with mysql    when a person tap on an some event then a picture + a button( contains url) gets retrieved from  database and when he tap on button he will redirect to website  (who's address is coded in the button event)      please just tell me the concept   how can i store   image and a button (containing link)  i think it is possible using datagrid

Comment: bhasker i hope u understand hindi   yaar main na windows app bana rha hu jo  mysql se connected hogi  and jab main tap karunga to images fetch honi start ho jaaye  or unke saath ek link bhi aaye jo main database me store karaunga  and jab us link pe click karu to wo mujhe site par le jaaye   . mene search kara hai  i think datagrid se buttons save ho jaynge  mysql me   ........ images to mene store karwa li hai